# Converting time to UTC using java 8

Tags: java, utc, java-time, timezone-offset

I have some APIs in Java which accept times as strings.

The UI sends plain string like `"10:00:00"`. I am creating a `LocalTime` out of that and saving in the db (MySQL).

Later in another API I use a `LocalDate` object and the above time with Zone UTC to create a `ZonedDateTime` object that is saved to the db. My problem is that the time is not getting converted to UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")),LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")),dto.getStart(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Both of these are different though I am sending for eg `07:00:00` which is my time in India. Please guide me as to how I should convert the time alone to UTC.

EDIT:: I have set jvm Duser.Timezone to UTC.When I do this:

```
ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")),dto.getStart(), ZoneId.of("UTC")).getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
```

It gives 0 as seconds

EDIT::

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta");
ZoneId z1 = ZoneId.of("UTC");
TimeZone.getTimeZone(z).getRawOffset();
```

Tried this and it gives the diff in ms. I will try using this provided the UI sends the actual local zone. Will update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now We have decided to allow the UI to change the time to whatever is its timezone. JVM timezone for the server is set to UTC...

Answer (score 2):

If the input corresponds to your local time, you can create a `ZonedDateTime` to get the current date in India timezone, set the time and then convert it to UTC:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:00:00"); // 10 AM

ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime
    .now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")) // current date/time in India
    .with(time) // set time to 10 AM
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC); // convert to UTC
```

The value of variable `utc` will be `2018-01-29T04:30Z` (running the code today, January 29th). The time in UTC is 4:30 AM, which is equivalent to 10 AM in India.

I believe that MySQL can't save a `ZonedDateTime`, so you can first convert it to an `Instant` by calling `utc.toInstant()`. Or if the driver you use is an older version and it works only with `java.util.Date`, you can convert it using `Date.from(utc.toInstant())`.

Also note that I used the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`, which is equivalent to (but better than, IMO) calling `ZoneId.of("UTC")`.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against storing a ZonedDateTime in a MySQL database. MySQL timestamps don't store the timezone information so you can't guarantee you'll get back the same time that you save.

Instead I would store a LocalDateTime and standardise on UTC for internal times and then format with a timezone when you need to display etc. To get the current time in UTC you can do something like this.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
```

To build a UTC timestamp for today and a provided time you could do something like this.

```
LocalTime time = getTime();
LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(Clock.systemUTC()), time);
```

To build a timestamp using the date for the current timezone, a provided time and then convert to UTC for saving to the database.

```
ZoneId timezone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta");
LocalTime time = getTime();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(timezone), time, timezone);
LocalDateTime utcDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(zdt.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```